# Self rendered tiles don't look the same as on the OSM website

Tags: openstreetmap

I have generated my own tiles for part of the Great Britain using the osm.pbf file from here [1] and the style sheets from here [2].

I'm using Mapnik version 3.0.9 and generating the tiles using the polytiles.py script from [3]

As I understand it the OSM website uses the same style sheets but my tiles don't look the same as the OSM ones. For example, the road colors are different and some road labels don't line up between tiles.

OSM Screen Shot

[image]

My Tiles Screen Shot

[image]

[1] http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html
[2] https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git
[3] http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik

Comment: https://blog.openstreetmap.org/2015/10/30/openstreetmap-org-map-changing/ Your link [2] seems to point to correct repository, when did you download the styles?

Comment: @user30184 A couple of days ago.. The latest commit I have is 7b8998c089b448dd73e54cd05c2321c99d529b95

Comment: Your second image shows indeed the old style before the change mentioned by @user30184. With the current style there are no green roads any more. Are you sure that you are using the openstreetmap-carto style sheet at all?

Comment: Here is my osm2pgsql command...

osm2pgsql --create --slim \
    --username postgres \
    --cache 1000 --number-processes 4 --hstore \
    --style /root/osm/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style --multi-geometry \
    /root/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm using the polytiles.py script from https://github.com/openstreetmap/mapnik-stylesheets/blob/master/polytiles.py which uses a style sheet osm.xml not the one I've downloaded.